# Drawer layout has overridden the background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have a small but bothering problem.

I have a drawable layout for my sliding menu, but when I put it in my XML, the background is totally untouchable because the drawer has filled and overridden on screen:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:background="@drawable/background_tabs" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/colors"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        android:background="@drawable/antartica8"
        tools:context=".ListViewActivity" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
    >

        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:background="@color/list_background" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/colors"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF666666"
            android:onClick="onColorClicked"
            android:tag="#FF666666" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF96AA39"
            android:onClick="onColorClicked"
            android:tag="#FF96AA39" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFC74B46"
            android:onClick="onColorClicked"
            android:tag="#FFC74B46" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF4842D"
            android:onClick="onColorClicked"
            android:tag="#FFF4842D" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF3F9FE0"
            android:onClick="onColorClicked"
            android:tag="#FF3F9FE0" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF5161BC"
            android:onClick="onColorClicked"
            android:tag="#FF5161BC" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I solve this? Is there anything like "always on top" to cast on background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Layout for an activity which needs to use the navigation drawer should be like this. The Nav Drawer is showing up on top because you're placing the views in an incorrect order.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- This is where you'll add views to display in the Activity-->
    <!-- E.g. FrameLayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <!-- The View that you place at the last is shown in the navigation drawer.
        In this case, the following RelativeLayout will be shown in the 
        navigation drawer. -->
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_relative_layout">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```