# Use an Image for DrawerLayout background

Tags: android, android-layout

I've search on line and here, but I can not find any usefull answer on : "How can I set an Image as a background for my NavigationDrawer's ListView ?"

The problem is whenever my ListView's background isn't a "solid" color (#aabbcc for example), the DrawerLayout doesn't show.

Here's my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#aabbcc"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
             />        
    [... Rest of main layout ...]
```

If I change the `android:background="#aabbcc"` to `android:background="@drawable/menu_bg"`, my app screen just get grey and the Drawer doesn't show.

Solutions I(ve try but doesn't work (same result) :
[DrawerLayout background for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645125/drawerlayout-background-for-listview)
[Drawer layout has overridden the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748632/drawer-layout-has-overridden-the-background)

Is it possible to set an Image instead of a single color in a NavigationDrawer ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about making the drawer a `RelativeLayout` and adding an `ImageView` underneath the `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- Your main layout -->
</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_bg"
        android:src="@drawable/img2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm following the Android's training guide to DrawerLayout, I don't see why I should a RelativeLayout instead of a DrawerLayout ?
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Doesn't work either. The only thing I can do to make it work is add a solid color as a beackground for this "new" relative Layout, but the image doesn't show.

Comment: @Memo36 what about setting the background of this RelativeLayout to a drawable? Works for me.

Comment: Still the same, solid color is fine, drawable isn't. You can check the xml in original question.

Comment: Finally got it working. Really don't know why but eh >.<

Comment: Edit your answer by moving the ... Rest of main layout ...] inside the FrameLayout to get the Accepted answer mark please ;)